# Sending a header that is stored as a string in a variable

Tags: php, eval

I have a function that builds an HTTP header to be send the user. So:

```
$header = build_header($param1, $param2);

// the function build_header will return the header I want to send as a string, e.g.:
// $header == 'header("location: http://example.com", true, 303)';
```

So now I have the header as a string. I could do this:

```
eval($header);
```

But will this work as intended, and is it safe? (The parameters that are used in the `build_header` function are all defined in a `config.php` file, so a visitor can't smuggle some malicious code in the `eval()`-statement.). Or is there a better way to send the header? I know I could just get rid of the functions and build the header directly instad of storing it in a variable, but I feel like that would mess up the seperation of controller and view ...

Comment: Header is controller side. before any call to the view. you should not need this trick if your MVC was good...

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful indeed /s. I know the header comes before the view. In this case I'm dealing with a location header, so there is no view at all.  (I put it like that in my question to avoid overcomplicating it). I'm just asking how to send the header given this structure, not how I could've structured it instead

Comment: If you ask how to make a Nuke weapon to kill a fly, I'll tell you to get a newspaper instead. `eval()` is a bad practice, so yes it'll work, no, you should not use it. `header("location: ".HOME_PAGE, true, 303)` use a var too, but don't need a `eval()` call...

Comment: Ok i will do that then. Would still like to know what the best practice would be given these restrictions. You know, for science.

Comment: You don't put enough code in your post to help us telling you the best way (that's why I tell you to use the recommended/world-assumed one). And I think you problem is more in the use you do of MVC, you *may* misunderstood something if you got this kind of things... (a lot like "what are the Nuclear fallout when you kill a fly?" ='D )

Comment: It's fine, I'll just go with what you said